# Elegance: How to better flatten an active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to get a simple hash of results through a join. I'm getting the correct output, but I hate my implementation of it.

Here's my current attempt:

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :position_synonyms
end

class PositionSynonym < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :position
end
```

Here's my current attempt. I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this:

```
def flat
result = []
Position.all.includes(:position_synonyms).each do |p|
  result.push({id:p.id, name: p.name})
  if p.position_synonyms
    p.position_synonyms.each do |s|
      result.push({id:p.id, name:s.name})
    end
  end
end
result
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could try:

```
def flat
  Position.select(:id, :name).map{|p| {id: p.id, name: p.attributes}} +
  PositionSynonyms.select(:position_id, :name).map{|s| {id: s.position_id, name: s.name}}
end
```

or the probably better performing:

```
def flat
  Position.pluck(:id, :name).map{|p| {id: p[0], name: p[1]} } +
  PositionSynonyms.pluck(:position_id, :name).map{|s| {id: s[0], name: s[1]} }
end
```